# How to create an autocomplete list in ViM?

Tags: vim

As I am typing code, I would like to get the symbol before and after a specific character (e.g. '.' in C#) and pass that to my own program which would then in return give a list of possible completions.

For example if user is typing:

```
m_Filename.M
```

I would want to call out into my own DLL/EXE passing "m_Filename" and "M" and my program return a list such as

```
Match
Matches
```

And have that popup in a list in ViM for autocompletion suggestions.

Note that this is not asking how to write the DLL/EXE which provides the suggestions, just the functionality in ViM for autocomplete .

Comment: Not an answer really, but you could look at the Supertab plugin and see how that does it / go from there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In vim, see `:help 'omnifunc'` and `:help complete-functions`. You can write your own vim function to do completions, and that function can, in turn, invoke an external executable.